# Subquery with inner join and not exist(?)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this code:

```
SELECT b.id_book 
    INTO var_idbook
    FROM ORDERS o
    INNER JOIN SIGNATURES s
    ON o.signature=s.signature
    INNER JOIN BOOKS b ON s.id_book=b.id_book
    WHERE ((b.genre=var_genre))
    GROUP BY b.id_book
    ORDER BY COUNT(o.ID_ORDER) DESC
    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

This code works fine and it's goal is to give a *id_book* of a book that is the most popular in certain genre. I'd like to check if a user borrowed this book before because I don't want to recommend him the book that he read once.
I have a table named ORDERS where I have history of orders and attrubutes: *ID_ORDER*, *ID_READER* and *SIGNATURE* and also table *SIGNATURES* where I have *SIGNATURE* and *ID_BOOK*. When I invoke this method I use *ID_READER* but I have no idea how to modify this code to have a history checked.
Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the not exists in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT b.id_book 
  INTO var_idbook
  FROM ORDERS o
 INNER JOIN SIGNATURES s
    ON o.signature=s.signature
 INNER JOIN BOOKS b 
    ON s.id_book=b.id_book
 WHERE b.genre=var_genre
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM ORDERS o2 
                    INNER JOIN SIGNATURES s2
                       ON o2.signature = s2.signature
                    WHERE o2.id_reader = var_reader
                      AND s2.id_book   = s.id_book)
GROUP BY b.id_book
ORDER BY COUNT(o.ID_ORDER) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Since I don't have a proper dataset I can't test it, but the idea is to have a lookup for the id_book to see if the user ordered it and filter it out. The subquery is joined to the outer query by id_book and a parameter *var_reader* is used to select the user.

EDIT:
For an interesting discussion on EXISTS / NOT EXISTS and IN / NOT IN please refer to the link below:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:442029737684

Comment: And what does it mean: "SELECT 1"?

Comment: "SELECT 1" means you are actually not worried about returning any column, you are just testing the condition of existance (the WHERE clause). There are also people who write "SELECT NULL".

Comment: I've added a link on the reply for a discussion on AskTom about EXISTS / NOT EXISTS that may be helpful clarifying things a bit further

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide information about relation between `ORDER` and `BOOKS`. MY assume: there is table `ORDER_BOOK_LINK` with book_id and order_id

```
SELECT b.id_book 
    -- INTO var_idbook
    FROM ORDERS o
    INNER JOIN SIGNATURES s ON o.signature=s.signature
    INNER JOIN BOOKS b ON s.id_book=b.id_book
    WHERE b.genre=var_genre
      AND NOT EXSITS (SELECT NULL 
                        FROM ORDER_BOOK_LINK obl 
                       WHERE obl.Order_id = o.D_ORDER 
                         AND obl.book_id = b.id_book )
    GROUP BY b.id_book
    ORDER BY COUNT(o.ID_ORDER) DESC
    --FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
    ;
```